# Automation.RawViewCondition Does not Exist (Reference)

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation

I am trying to write

```
var cacheRequest = new CacheRequest
{
   AutomationElementMode = AutomationElementMode.None,
   TreeFilter = Automation.RawViewCondition//reference
};
```

I am getting an error ,

> the type or namespace name 'RawViewCondition' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Automation' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am using this namespaces

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;
using Automation = System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

I am new to UI Automation.
There would be great appreciation if someone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

Got my answer we must use System.Windows.Automation.Automation.RawViewCondition. Thanks any way to all.